# Laravel returned only one records in foreach. Why?

Tags: php, laravel, return

I have this foreach loop:

```
 $productStan = product::all();   
 foreach ($productStan as $stan) {
     return $date = $stan->stan_key;
 }
```

And this is my table `products`:
[image]

This is all records from:

```
return $productStan;
```

> [{"id":1,"user_id":1,"stan":3,"stan_key":"user,3","article_id":1,"category_id":1,"sn":"1111","quantity":12,"warranty":"2016-07-27","created_at":"2016-07-27
>   22:45:36","updated_at":"2016-07-29
>   08:55:38"},{"id":2,"user_id":1,"stan":2,"stan_key":"user,2","article_id":2,"category_id":2,"sn":"8sd8adada9d08ada90d89","quantity":20,"warranty":"2016-07-28","created_at":"2016-07-28
>   18:33:20","updated_at":"2016-07-28 18:33:20"}]

When I want returned variable `$date`, Laravel return only one records:
**user,3**
But when I write `echo` instead `return` like this:

```
echo $date = $stan->stan_key;
```

Laravel returned correct two records:
**user,3user,2**

In my method I must returned all records from table `products`.

*What am I doing wrong, that laravel returned only the LATEST record, and not returned all records ??*

Comment: 'return' means it ends the method and returns the supplied value, so it never gets to the second iteration.

Answer (score 4):

You need to return an array to return multiple item.

```
$productStan = product::all();    
$date = array();
foreach ($productStan as $stan) {
   $date[] = $stan->stan_key;
}

return $date;
```

Comment: Thanks, but Laravel returned records in the form: ["user,3","user,2"], how I can change this records on: user,3user,2 without brackets and quotes??

Answer (score 1):

Because at first iteration the `return` statement is encountered and that cause the program to exit.

You can `return $productStan` directly and perform the `foreach` loop where you want to display/use the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $productStan = product::all();    
        $date = array();
        foreach ($productStan as $stan) {
            $date['id'] = $stan->stan_key;
      $date['uid'] = $stan->user_id;
     $date['aid'] = $stan->artical_id;

                }

     print_r($date);
   return Statement doesn`t seems accurate here. You have records in $date array, now you can play around it.
```